# Get the highest of three integers unless two are equal

Tags: javascript, math, integer, comparison

So I need to compare three integers which look like this:

```
const optionOne = 2
const optionTwo = 1
const optionThree = 0
```

I need to determine which integer is the highest. However, there are three "voting rounds" in the application, so I have the special case of a three way tie:

```
const optionOne = 1
const optionTwo = 1
const optionThree = 1
```

In which case I want to default to optionOne. How to do this?

Comment: For the first part: `Math.max.apply(Math, [optionOne, optionTwo, optionThree])`; for the second: they are all the same O.o

Comment: One `1` is as good as another

Comment: Unclear. What is a "voting round" ? What constitutes a vote ? Explain more.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getHighest(one, two, three){
    if(one !== two && two !== three){
        if(one > two){
            if(one > three){
                return 1;
            }else{
                return 3;
            }
        }else{
            if(two > three){
                return 2;
            }else{
                return 3;
            }
        }
    }else{
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Calling getHighest() and passing the three values will return the biggest number option, not the number. I.e: if the second value is the bigger, it will return "2", so you know that the second is the bigger, whichever is it's value.
If there is a tie between 2 or the 3 values, it will return 1

Answer (score 0):

int getHighest(int optionOne,int optionTwo,int optionThree)
{
int ans=optionOne>optionTwo?(optionOne>optionThree?optionOne:optionThree):optionTwo>OptionThree?optionTwo:optionThree;
return ans;
}